# Java: reflection (at runtime) versus mirroring (at annotation processing)

Tags: java, reflection, types, mirroring, annotation-processing

I understand the general differences between the concepts of

- **reflection** (done at **runtime** using `Class, Method, Field, Annotation, ...`), and
- **mirroring** (done during **annotation processing** using `TypeMirror, TypeElement, ...`).

But can someone please compare the two concepts in-depth (or point me to a resource, where it is done)?

*For instance, which concept offers what kinds of information that the other does not offer...*

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Reflection classes are used to represent the classes of objects *in a running JVM*. Reflection is a very old concept that has been present in Java since the very beginning. As such, it is a bit clunky in some areas, having been extended to accomodate new language constructs (especially generics).
- The classes in `javax.lang.model` are used to work with *Java source code*. They were designed when Generics already existed and can (and have to) support them much more extensively, since they are used *before* type erasure happens.

Comment: Thank you. But, as I mentioned, the general concepts are known, and I was hoping for an in-depth analysis. BTW, I think the statement that reflection has been extended to support generics is wrong, as you mentioned by yourself, they are erased during runtime.

Comment: Oh, I see, by saying that java.lang.reflect was extended for generics, you probable are referring to `java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable`. Hmm, never used it, will inform myself about it...

Comment: @java.is.for.desktop: the type parameters of objects are erased, but the type parameters in field, method and class definitions are not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the answer in [this paper](http://bracha.org/mirrors.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the paper but it's really hard to read since it's intended for the research audience. It would be great if you can briefly describe it from a technical perspective.